# Trouble viewing application on physical device

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my app in physical devic

[image]

This is my app in emulator

[image]

I have a problem in view the application in the real machine as you see in image1 Changing right to left and vice versa . While this problem does not exist in the emulator as you see in image2 .

Comment: What's the default Locale and system language set on the device? I am guessing the `gravity` of the `TextView` with the label _The result is:_ set to `start` (instead of `left`) to support LTR (_Left to Right_) and RTL (_Right to Left_) languages and the device is set to use a LTR language. But, post your code for better clarity anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the whole thing in support of Right-to-left,
see locale on your device and emulator.
Do you have `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file?

More info there - http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: Thanks alot i delete the term android:supportsRtl="true" from my manifest file and the problem resolved